# Hello, how do I iterate through a map that has a list inside which then has the map objects in dart

Tags: flutter

```
{members: [{name: vikali, id: 30, member_name: Julia, msisdn: 254712345321}, {name: vikali, id: 31, 
member_name: Eustero, msisdn: 254721323237}, {name: vikali, id: 29, member_name: Tony, msisdn: 
254700149662}]}
```

I want to access the names in the map. I get a single name using  `print(members['members'][0]['name'])`

Comment: why do you have a map called members that just contains one key named members? Wouldn't it be easier to just have a list called members with the maps inside?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert members list to list of names by `map` function:

```
members['members'].map((member) => member['name']).toList()
```